# Xcode didSelectRowAtIndexPath on tableview not called

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have been looking until 6 o'clock this morning, but I can't figure out why the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not being called. I am getting quite desparate on this one.

The tableview is shown properly, but I cannot succeed to enable the selection of a cell.

In the header file , I added:

```
@interface AlertsTable : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CMPopTipViewDelegate>{
    UITableView *TableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   UITableView *TableView;
```

In the implementation file:

```
@synthesize TableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    //Set the title


    //Format Alerts table
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    CGFloat sideMargin = 10;
    CGFloat topBottomMargin = 44;
    CGFloat originX = sideMargin;
    // compute width based on view size
    CGFloat sizeWidth = (self.view.bounds.size.width - (sideMargin * 2));
    CGFloat originY = topBottomMargin;
    // compute height based on view size
    CGFloat sizeHeight = (self.view.bounds.size.height - (topBottomMargin * 2));
    //self.view.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);

    self.TableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];


    //Initialize the array.
    AlertsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Alert 1", @"Alert 2", @"Alert 3" , @"Alert 4", @"Alert 5", @"Alert 6", nil];

[self.TableView setDelegate:self];
[self.TableView setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:TableView];
TableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
TableView.allowsSelection = YES;
TableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
NSLog(@"delegate:%@ dataSource:%@", self.TableView.delegate, self.TableView.dataSource);

}
```

The delegate and datasource are both not nil on the check.
Note that the "Alertstable" inherits from a UIViewController, not a UITableViewController.
This is necessary due to the implementation I chose: the tableview is shown on a popupwindow shown on the screen (using another class that I took from the internet).

This is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicked on row #%d", [indexPath row]];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertString message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

The methods:

```
[super touchesBegan:...];  
[super touchesEnded:...];  
[super touchesMoved:...];
```

are not implemented.

I added the AlertTable from another ViewController

```
AlertsTable *AlertTable = [[AlertsTable alloc] WithButton:sender withArray:self.PopTipViews];
[self.view addSubview:AlertTable.view];
```

I also implemented:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[AlertsItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog (@"%@",[AlertsItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    return cell;

}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?
I'm not very experienced in Xcode and I'm really stuck.

Edit:

I know that it is not custom, but the link to the project can be found here (perhaps I'm overlooking something:

https://www.bilbu.be/BarConnect_v2.zip

The LoginViewController.xib is not properly linked (it is available in the en.lproj subfolder) so you may need to link first (I noticed too late and I had the file uploaded by a friend before - I cannot re-upload it myself unfortunately).
ViewController VC class calls the AlertsTable VC class. There is more in the project that I suppose you can ignore...
Note that the purpose of this project is only to serve as visual interface prototype. It is not meant to be the best optimized application (this is what other developers will do). If this doesn't work, I will use Photoshop to create the interfaces, but I guess that's not gonna be as convincing...

Comment: did you alloc and init your TableView?

Comment: Was the DataSource implemented correctly? (eg. cellForRowAtIndexPath:)

Another question: are u using a storyboard?

Comment: Hello yes, I alloced and init. I also implemented cellForRowAtIndexPath. I will edit my original post, and add this code. As mentioned below, I will upload the path Xcode project asap, but I have to wait until my friend sends me the link.

Comment: I don't use a storyboard. Sorry for the late reply to this.

Comment: Thanks, the link to the project is https://www.bilbu.be/BarConnect_v2.zip The LoginViewController.xib is not properly linked so you may need to do that I noticed too late. ViewController VC class calls the AlertsTable VC class. There is more in the project that I suppose you can ignore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully compiled your project. The problem is that you're going against the MVC pattern. The controller (`AlertsTable`) is inside of a view (`CMPopTipView`). I'd suggest you to rethink the hierarchy of the controllers and views. Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 because that actually did help me. As I mentioned, I'm quite new in Xcode development, so when having read about MVC, I immediately understood that I'm taking the wrong road. I'm going to clearly separate views from controllers ans rebuild from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you've found my answer good, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: I will change the structure of the views / controllers and see if I manage to make it work this weekend. I prefer to leave this post open until after the weekend, just in case I get some additional feedback. But I'll accept your answer if it turns out that it was the source of my problem. Thanks

Comment: OK, thanks! BTW, note that also Apple's `UIPopoverController` (similar to your `CMPopTipView`) is a controller, not a view.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip. As a matter of fact, I think that I will go for the UIPopoverController. Apparently I'm extending the reach of this class too far for what it was meant to deliver.

Comment: `UIPopoverController` is available only on the iPad. You may want to check some clones on GitHub that work also on the iPhone.

Comment: I see; that's a pity! The class I imported allows dynamic resizing to the content of the contained view and adapts dynamically to the location of the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
TableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
TableView.allowsSelection = YES;
TableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

to

```
self.TableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.TableView.allowsSelection = YES;
self.TableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

and are you allocating self.TableView? Something like...

```
self.TableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];//[[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: Hello I will answer in the evening because I have a meeting for my project. Thank you and I will check.

Comment: Hello, I made the changes. The code I applied was: self.TableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain]; Unluckily with the same result. I will upload the Xcode file asap and provide the link, but I have to ask a friend to upload it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you loaded anything into your tableView by the way?
I think if you have not, that may be your problem...

Comment: Hello, yes I added an Array with test items... Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: I have one more idea...
was this build completely programmatically or in IB and connected?

Comment: The implementation is entirely performed programmatically.

Comment: if it is completely programatic and you are not getting anything if, it is programatic it needs to be added to the view like this.
`[self.view addSubview:self.TableView];`
actually though, looking at your code again, I am really confused now though..hahah sorry.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help! I tried to add self to TableView, but it doesn't give a difference. This evening I have the project file, and I'll upload it. I would be grateful if someone could have a brief look. After a long night reading every forum on the topic I'm getting quite frustrated and I am as stuck as I can possibly be...

Comment: ok, but the way it looks to me here, self.TableView and TableView are two different tables.... so you should always be referring to this one table as self.TableView, and you do not need the other one even in the implementation i think.

Comment: Thanks, the link to the project is https://www.bilbu.be/BarConnect_v2.zip The LoginViewController.xib is not properly linked so you may need to do that I noticed too late. ViewController VC class calls the AlertsTable VC class. There is more in the project that I suppose you can ignore...

Comment: Can you reupload it with the LoginViewController.xib?

Comment: Hello, the xib is in a subfolder called en.proj. No idea how it got there! I know that it is not very corteous, but unfortunately, the upload was done via a friend of mine that is currently working on other things and doesn't have the time now. Otherwise I would certainly do. The loginviewcontroller has just a button that forwards to the ViewController class.